# JButton gets stuck until connection is made...

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextpane

I've made a simple chat server/client and have this problem

when the user clicks the button I want the button to change to "disconnect", write some stuff on a JTextPane object and do the connection.

the problem is nothing gets updated until the connection is made, the button gets stuck, also any writing to the JTextPane object is only seen after the connection (about 5-10 seconds).

any solution/advice?

```
        connectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (!running) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        connectButton.setText("disconnect");
                    }
                });
                running = true;
                connect();
            } 
            else {
                connectButton.setText("connect");
                running = false;
                disconnect();                   
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you should use a thread for `connect()`, instead of calling in a blocking way.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, prevent it from, amongst other things, process paint requests.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to understand what's going on and consider using a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to execute the connection in a separate thread, especially if you wan to update the UI in some way while the connection is been performed.

Answer (score 1):

Your Swing-Code is executed in a single Thread, so is your actionPerformed()-Method. Just start a new Thread or create a runnable and start it with SwingUtils.invokeLater():

Example:

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          //do something
        }
});
```